# Вставить из скрипта bash в другие терминалы gnome-terminal команду без запуска

Tags: bash, консоль

Запустить команду на выполнение могу, например так:
    `gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'crunch 5 5'"`
однако, при этом не получается потом в случае необходимости приостановить выполнение по Ctrl+z, только остановить. Заметил, что если в так же созданном терминале просто после `gnome-terminal` набрать ту же команду и запустить, то приостановка работает.
    Прошу совета либо -как запустить команду в другом терминале, но чтобы при этом Ctrl+z работало; либо как просто вписать из скрипта в терминал готовую команду без запуска, но не запускать ее, а запускать вручную? может это поможет?

Comment: `$ gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "set -m; crunch 5 5; $0"'` или `$ gnome-terminal -e 'bash -o monitor -c "crunch 5 5; $0"'`

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, спасибо, работает! Не подскажите ли еще как будет выглядеть подобный синтаксис в случае с pipes? `command 1 | command 2 | command 3` ?

Comment: точно так же и будет.

Comment: [по мотивам](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325220/110559): `gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "echo \"какой-нибудь текст\" | perl -e \"ioctl STDOUT, 0x5412, \\\$_ for split //, do{ chomp(\\\$_ = <>); \\\$_ }\"; $0"'`