# Вставка текста в командную строку bash программно

Tags: linux, bash, git-bash

Как запустить bash консоль с набранной командой в командной строке?

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1003042/178576)

Comment: `man sh` search: `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так (понадобится установить expect).

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn /bin/bash
send "my text to be posted"
interact
exit
```